# Looking for a regex to to Satisfy the following

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for a regex or logic in JavaScript to trap the following conditions

```
If a value begins with a number [space] Street call X

    5 Eastern 
    500 Eastern
    25 15th
```

..

```
If NO street number call Y

    Eastern
    15th St
    N Eastern
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than *looking* for a regex, why don't you try *writing* one? Take a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex you're looking for:

```
/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9][a-z]+/
```

Then in JS, use it in the following way:

```
if (/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test(value)) {
  x();
}
else {
  y();
}
```

`value` of course is the string that you are testing.

Tests...

```
/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('5 Eastern')
// => true

/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('500 Eastern')
// => true

/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('25 15th')
// => true

/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('Eastern')
// => false

/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('15th St')
// => false

/^\d+\s[A-Z0-9]+[a-z]+/.test('N Eastern')
// => false
```

Comment: Thank you!   I spent almost an hour playing with countless combinations